# Sortear letras em uma matriz, quantida digitada pelo usuario

Tags: java

estou tendo dificuldade aqui para poder o usuário digitar quantas letras de cada ele quer que seja sorteada. Exemplo como no código abaixo mostra as letras `char[] letras = new char[]{'S', 'C', 'M', 'A','L'};`. Essas letras elas são sorteada na matriz, mas quero fazer para o usuário digitar quantos `S`, quantos `C`, quantos `M` e assim por diante. Meu código é esse abaixo..

```
public class exemplo {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int tamanho = 4; 

        char[] letras = new char[]{'S', 'C', 'M', 'A','L'};
        char matrix [][] = new char[tamanho][tamanho];


        Random random = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < tamanho; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < tamanho; j++) {

                matrix[i][j] = letras[random.nextInt(letras.length)];

            }

        }
        for (int i = 0; i < tamanho; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < tamanho; j++) {
                System.out.print("|" + matrix[i][j] + "|");
            }

       System.out.println("");
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: O que aconteceria se a soma de S, C, M, A e L dadas pelo usuário for diferente de 16?

Comment: bem pensado, daria um grande erro

Comment: o que vc mim recomendaria fazer?

Comment: Depende. O que é que você quer fazer com isso? Porque é que você quer fazer isso?

Comment: para fazer um agente, distribuir letras na matriz para o agente procurar o s de sujeira e Limpar...

Answer (score 2):

Olá, bom, não sei se é exatamente oque você estava procurando mas essa foi minha solução,

Primeiro eu criei uma lista de caracteres para armazenar todas as letras possiveis a serem sorteadas,

```
List<Character> base_sorteio = new ArrayList<>();
```

Depois eu fiz um loop para solicitar ao usuario a quantidade desejada de cada letra utilizando a classe Scanner, logo em seguida eu adiciono a base de caracteres a quantidade inserida pelo usuario para aquele determinado caracter,

```
    int y = 0;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    for (int i = 0; i < letras.length; i++) {

        System.out.println("Informe a quantidade de '" + letras[i] + "'");

        int k = sc.nextInt();
        for (int f = 0; f < k; f++) {
            base_sorteio.add(letras[i]);
        }
    }
```

Após inserir os a quantidade de cada letra, a lista de caracteres ira armazenar algo como:

```
[S, C, C, C, C, M, M, M, M, M, A, A, A, L, L, L]
```

No caso a sima, eu digitei 1S,4C,5M,3A e 3L. Em seguida eu embaralho a lista,

```
Collections.shuffle(base_sorteio);
```

ficando assim:

```
[M, M, C, C, A, A, L, C, L, M, C, M, S, A, L, M]
```

Depois disso, é só adicionar essa lista a matriz:

```
    y = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < tamanho; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < tamanho; j++) {
            matrix[i][j] = base_sorteio.get(y);
            y++;
        }
    }
```

Segue abaixo o codigo completo:

```
import java.util.*;

public class exemplo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int tamanho = 4;

        char[] letras = new char[]{'S', 'C', 'M', 'A', 'L'};
        char matrix[][] = new char[tamanho][tamanho];

        List<Character> base_sorteio = new ArrayList<>();

        int y = 0;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        for (int i = 0; i < letras.length; i++) {

            System.out.println("Informe a quantidade de '" + letras[i] + "'");

            int k = sc.nextInt();
            for (int f = 0; f < k; f++) {
                base_sorteio.add(letras[i]);
            }
        }

        Collections.shuffle(base_sorteio);

        y = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < tamanho; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < tamanho; j++) {
                matrix[i][j] = base_sorteio.get(y);
                y++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("");
        for (int i = 0; i < tamanho; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < tamanho; j++) {
                System.out.print("|" + matrix[i][j] + "|");
            }

            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
}
```